# unrecognized expression a[href=javascript:void(0)]

Tags: jquery

I'm used jQuery 1.10.2 and on one page there is an error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression
>   a[href=javascript:void(0)]

In Developer Tools show error in first line jQuery library

Comment: show the full code, not just error?

Comment: Search for this snippet `$('a[href=javascript:void(0)]')` and replace this with `$('a[href="javascript:void(0)"]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

`$('a[href=javascript:void(0)]');`

You need to add quotes surrounding the value of the attribute:

`$('a[href="javascript:void(0)"]');`